# Electromagnetism magnetic field line

Tags: electromagnetism, conventions, earth, geomagnetism

What is the direction of the magnetic field of the Earth? From north to south or from south to north?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 1):

In general the direction of a magnetic field tells you in what direction the north pole of a small magnet would feel a force.  If you suspend a bar magnet so that it's free to rotate you will find that the north pole points north telling you that the Earth's magnetic field is (broadly) directed from south (antarctic) to north (arctic).  The north pole of a magnet is sometimes referred to as the north seeking pole.

What makes this subject a bit confusing is that we refer to the magnetic pole of the Earth in the arctic as the north magnetic pole even though it attracts the north poles of other magnets thereby acting like a south pole of a magnet.

Also, the magnetic poles of the the Earth do not correspond exactly with the geographic poles.  Currently the north magnetic pole is about 400 km from the geographic pole.  This means that at most locations on the Earth's surface the direction of the Earth's magnetic field does not correspond exactly with the direction to the north geographic pole which is the direction we consider north.  The difference in these two directions is referred to as the angle of declination.

One more thing, only near the equator is the Earth's magnetic field horizontal.  In the northern hemisphere it points down towards the ground at an increasingly steep angle of inclination as you approach the magnetic pole.  In the southern hemisphere it has a component pointing up away from the ground.

Comment: Scientists do not refer to the north geographic pole as the north magnetic pole.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Of course not.  Does my answer imply that they do?

Comment: You say "...we refer to the magnetic pole of the Earth in the arctic as the north magnetic pole..."  I was just clarifying that while non-scientists may call the north geographic pole the north magnetic pole, but it is not.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Sorry, but I'm still not understanding exactly what you're trying to say.  Do you think my answer does not make it clear that the north magnetic pole and the north geographic poles are different?  Or are you saying that the "scientists" do not refer to the magnetic pole in the arctic as the north magnetic pole?

Comment: The latter.  The magnetic pole in the arctic(antarctic) is the south(north) magnetic pole.

Comment: Can you show me an instance of where the pole in the arctic is referred to as the south magnetic pole?  See [The Magnetic Field of the Earth: Paleomagnetism, the Core, and the Deep Mantle](https://books.google.ca/books?hl=en&lr=&id=96APl4nK9lIC&oi=fnd&pg=PR13&dq=earth+magnetic+pole&ots=O78-v9T83q&sig=4aUaGAUsx5l9cCIc08NMRmkCAZA#v=onepage&q=north%20pole&f=false) page 96 or [Will the magnetic North Pole move to Siberia?](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2007EO290001/full). Are these not scientist writing?  Is there some deeper level of scientific writing where nomenclature is reversed?

Comment: Ugh, this is unfortunate that they have this switched.  The north(south) magnetic pole is where the field is parallel(anti-parallel) to the outward unit normal, i.e., in the southern geographic hemisphere.

Answer (score 1):

The *magnetic south pole* of the earth is close to its *geographic north pole* and the magnetic north pole is close to the geographic south pole. Thus the magnetic field on the lower latitude surface and surrounding space of the earth is pointing north. Thats how the magnetic north pole of a magnet was defined. Freely suspended it points towards the north.

Answer (score 0):

They are from South to North. Interesting note they flip from time to time on a large time scale.